# MATLAB order of execution for assignments

Tags: matlab

Why does

```matlab
x = 1:7;
x(1:8) = 1:9;
```

throw

```
Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides
have a different number of elements.
```

rather than

```
Index exceeds the number of array elements. Index must not
exceed 7.
```

It's the case in Python: first, evaluate to right of `=`, then to left of `=`, then the `=`:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(7)
x[7] = np.arange(8)[8]  # next try `[8]` -> `[7]`
```

(modified example as `0:7` == `0:6` == `0:999` when not indexing individual elements)

Comment: Because in MATLAB you can write `x=1:7; x(1:8)=1:8;`. In this case the size of the array is automatically increased.

Comment: I'm more looking for an equivalent of https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order , i.e. how syntax is parsed.

Comment: Whether MATLAB throws what type of exception here I think isn't related to the execution order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think you can derive an “execution order” from the error messages. Python in your example just happens to throw one error before the other.

In MATLAB, however, we have the function [`subsasgn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsasgn.html), which is called for custom classes for the syntax `x(s) = y`. This shows that the indexing on the left-hand side and the assignment are a single operation, you can’t do the one without the other. The indexing on the left-hand side does not trigger an evaluation of the indexed array, we don’t read what is currently there, we just write into those places.

Comment: So `subsasgn` is MAT's `__setitem__`. My description wasn't quite right - while it does first evaluate right (confirm by following the `# next`), after that, `__setitem__` is called, which then errors not per unpacking `x`, but the method's own bounds check.

Comment: I figure, more completely, the idea's that MATLAB doesn't execute commands "in pieces", but all at once (which is why we can't do `{1:2}(1:3)`)? And that the syntax rule here says to jump straight to `subsasgn`, whose assignment checking happens to check the left slicing before the right.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon It would need to check the leftmost slicing first, before it knows what the next slicing operation is working on. For any one specific class the order could be reversed though. Or maybe the indexing is defined in a way that is orthogonal, so the order is irrelevant. Within `subsasgn` and `subsref` you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon My argument is that Python’s `__setitem__` just happens to first check if the indexing is valid, before it compares the sizes of left and right hand arguments. This makes sense though, the indexing slice can contain negative values or missing values, meaning that you don’t know how many elements are selected until you evaluate the slicing itself. But this does not mean that the indexing is “evaluated” first, because all of this is happening in the context of the assignment. It is a single atomic operation.

Comment: _"Python's `__setitem__` just happens to"_ no. Again, try changing `x[7]` in my example to `x[8]`. The right side evaluates first. Can confirm this by writing a custom class with `__setitem__` and `print` statements, and do like `my_obj[1:2] = my_func()` (also `print` inside of `my_func`).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Of course the right side is evaluated first, I didn’t think this was part of the argument. That is standard in all languages, it wouldn’t make sense otherwise. You need a value before you can assign it to something. I was talking about the part “then to left of `=`, then the `=`”. Those two are not separate operations.

Comment: In `a[0] = b()`, `b()` can execute without `a.__setitem__` ever executing. So in this sense they are separate, unlike in MATLAB.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Those are separate in MATLAB as well. The return value of `b()` would be passed to `subsasgn` or `__setitem__`. `a(0)=b()` is the same as `a = subsasgn(a,0,b())`, which would be evaluated by first evaluating the arguments to the function call, then calling the function. [2nd argument to `subsasgn` is a `substruct`, not just `0`, but you get the idea]. In the same way that `foo(bar())` would first call `bar()` and then `foo()` in *any* language.

Comment: Oh, huh. Right, my examples aren't 1-to-1: `y=1:9; x(1:8)=y(1:10)` works as expected. So indeed both work essentially same here, just Python's check order (and actually method itself, checking slicing vs the slice itself) differs. Though there still appears to be a fundamental difference in syntax parsing in that, Python evaluates _expressions_ left-to-right, so chained commands are always as valid as separate, unlike in MATLAB (e.g. `x(1:2)(1:3)`).